# How do I interpret an OPLS-DA scores plot with three groups?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

I have an OPLS-DA plot with three groups.

When comparing two groups, the x axis is the first predictive component and the y axis is the orthogonal component.

However, when looking at three groups, SIMCA software defaults to the x axis being predictive component 1 and the y axis to predictive component 2.

What practical difference does this make to the score plot, and how should I interpret this differently to a two group multivariate analysis?